How to accept autocompletion suggestions in Vim from Github Copilot with TAB key?
I'm trying to get Copilot.vim to work in regular Vim.
:Copilot status returns Copilot ready, and I can see suggestions as a "ghost" or grey text. When I try to accept them with Tab, a tab character gets inserted into the text, and the completion goes away.
Reading the copilot.vim documentation, they suggest something like this:
imap <silent><script><expr> <C-J> copilot#Accept("\<CR>")
let g:copilot_no_tab_map = v:true

That doesn't seem to work for me (hitting Ctrl+J).
I tried a few different things, including loading a baseline empty .vimrc but I don't seem to get anything to work properly.
Other regular key mappings I have in my config work just fine.
Any suggestions for how to troubleshoot this?
Vim version:
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.1 (2024 Jan 02, compiled Sep 25 2024 10:13:04)
Included patches: 1-16, 647, 678, 697
...
+textprop

Running imap <Tab> shows:
i  <Tab>       & empty(get(g:, 'copilot_no_tab_map')) ? copilot#Accept() : "\t"

I'm starting to suspect that the problem might have something to do that I'm connecting via SSH to a Linux server where Vim is running, but my client is a Windows 11 terminal.

Welcome to Vim! Could you tell us what is the result of imap <Tab>?

Thanks @VivianDeSmedt. It's i  <Tab>       & empty(get(g:, 'copilot_no_tab_map')) ? copilot#Accept() : "\t"

Could you tell us what is the value of g:copilot_no_tab_map (e.g. :echo g:copilot_no_tab_map)?

Thanks for walking me through this. It will be useful for next time!
The value is v:true

Then you have to make it v:false (:let g:copilot_no_tab_map =  0) otherwise the mapping make that <tab> is mapped to  "\t" which is also <tab> and not copilot#Accept().

I think I found out, thanks to a colleague!
The problem is that I have set paste enabled in my ~/.vimrc, and that breaks all mappings as I understand.
I can confirm that by adding set nopaste, or commenting out set paste, Copilot suggestions can be accepted normally with tab.

Don’t :set paste unless you’re pasting, as is documented at :help 'paste' and probably at :help 'pastetoggle'
